# Media Temple GS Problems Including Custom Pear Packages

Tags: mediatemple, pear

I have PEAR setup and custom packages installed under the directory

/home/######/data/pear/php

I can ssh in and confirm the files are there, however I can not include them in my application as such

```
require_once "/home/######/data/pear/php/Mail/Queue.php";
```

I get an error

Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I have also tried setting my php include_path to 
Local: /home/######/data/pear/php
Master: .:/home/######/data/pear/php

and received the same error using:

```
require_once "/Mail/Queue.php";
```

Another odd thing is that the "/pear/php" directory does not appear in place over ftp, but instead in an "..mnt/######/users/.home/pear/php/" directory

Technical Support tells me that custom PEAR packages are not a supported issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Mediatemple Knowledgebase,

[this](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/149/How+can+I+use+PEAR+on+my+%28mt%29+Media+Temple+server%3F#gs) link helped me. try

[took little time to figure out]

This problem happens because of the symbolic links in media temple, 
for example, the home directory path is */home/0000/user/.home/*

so your pear path will be `/home/0000/user/.home/pear/php`

Comment: Any useful information other than just posting a link?

Comment: @Khaled Sorry about that, I was in a hurry, so thought that link will help, Just added little more description, Thnaks for your patience :-)